# What is build tools version actually mean? Same as target version, min version, too. How dose these numbers affect the project？

Tags: android, version

I ve been confused by this question for long time since started develop Android. Thanks in advance, please explain it as exhaustive as well.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning.html Most exaustive answer i could manage

Comment: What book on Android app development did you read? Any good book should explain these concepts.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thank U very much if you can share some good books with me.

Comment: "Thank U very much if you can share some good books with me" -- well, I like [mine](https://commonsware.com/Android), but I am sure that there are plenty of others.

Answer (score 0):

- Build Tools version: version of the tools you use to build your project, doesn't affect project that much (unless there's a new feature in newer build tools)
- Target version: the Android API version you build your app against - you can use only features available in the API you target, newer methods won't be available to you. You should always target the newest Android API
- Minimal version: the minimal Android API version your app works with - the system won't install app with minSdkVersion higher than it's API version, so you should keep this as low as possible.

Comment: Thanks a lot，what if the build tools version is 21, and the user phone's system version is 25? Would the app run with sdk spi 21?